# Double or Square python function

Tags: python, function, math

I have been trying to create a double or square function on python where the result is to give the user the biggest number back when doubling or squaring. The problem states:

> double(x) returns 2 * x square(x) returns x**2 double_or_square(x) returns the larger number between double(x) and square(x)

My code so far has been:

```
def double(x):
    return (2 * x)
def square(x):
    return (x ** 2)
def double_or_square(x):
    return max(d, q)
d = double
q = square
```

I keep getting errors, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You weren't CALLING any of these functions.  Of course, the only integer where "double" will be larger is 1.

Do it like this:

```
def double(x):
    return 2 * x
def square(x):
    return x ** 2
def double_or_square(x):
    d = double(x)
    q = square(x)
    return max(d, q)
print( double_or_square( 2 ) )
print( double_or_square( 9 ) )
```